# Filter and get items from BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I have a BehaviorSubject which is filled calling an API with HttpClient:

```
  let parents = new BehaviorSubject<Parent[]>([]);

   this.httpClient.get<Parent[]>('parents-and-children').subscribe(result => {
     parents.next(result);
   });
```

Parent and Children class are:

```
class Parent {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  childrens: Children[];
}

class Children {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

I am looking to do the following:

1. Given a parentId value get the parent with that id from BehaviourSubject.
2. Given a childrenId value get the children with that id by looking into all parents' children.

   ```
   let parentId = 1;
   parents.pipe( ??

   let childrenId = 2;
   parents.pipe( ??
   ```

I have been trying pipe but I am not sure how to filter the items ...

Comment: [rxjs filter operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html). Not too tough to use. Easy to find, too, with a simple search.

Comment: You either have to subscribe to the BehaviorSubject and it'll emit its value or you can use `getValue()` function or just `value` property https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject#getValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let parentId = 1;
let childrenId = 2;

parents.pipe(
    map(parnts => parnts.find(p => p.id === parentId))
).subscribe(parent => console.log(parent));

parents.pipe(
    map(parnts => [].concat(...parnts.map(p => p.childrens))),
    map(childrens => childrens.find(ch => ch.id === childrenId))
).subscribe(child => console.log(child));
```

Comment: id is not recognised as property in ch.id as ch is a double array

Comment: fixed the answer using [].concat @MiguelMoura